# Excel Tables by Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, mail-merge

I have a spreadsheet that includes student name, parent name, class and t-shirt size, with one row for each student. I would like to draw from this to create a new table, where each class is a row, and the names of all of the students in the class and their emergency contacts are columns. I would also like another worksheet where the shirt sizes are rows, and each student is a column. My end goal is to use mail merge to generate a list of students for each teacher and a list of who should get each size t-shirt. 
It seems like VLookup should be able to do it, or maybe there is a way with a pivot table.

Here is an example input

[image: Here is an example input]

and outputs:

[image: outputs]

Can someone help me figure out how to get Excel to generate that information? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, Whats the question?

Comment: I will edit it to clarify. But I am wondering how to get Excel to reformat the data like in my output example.

Comment: @JustinGatlin,, no need to edit the Question since both Screen Shots are enough to solve the issue,, check the post below !

Answer (score 2):

**This Array Formula will solve the issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in Cell `G88` to get **Table by T- 
  Shirt:**

  `{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$88:$A$92,SMALL(IF($B$88:$B$92=$F88,ROW($A$88:$A$92)-MIN(ROW($A$88:$A$92))+1),COLUMNS($F$88:F88))),"")}`

**N.B.**

- Finish the Formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter.**
- Fill Formula Down the Right.

---

- Formula in Cell `G94` to get **Table by Name & 
  Contact Number:**

  `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$88:$A$92,SMALL(IF($C$88:$C$92=$F94,ROW($A$88:$A$92)-MIN(ROW($A$88:$A$92))+1),COLUMNS($F$94:F94)))," ")&"   "& IFERROR(INDEX($D$88:$D$92,SMALL(IF($C$88:$C$92=$F94,ROW($D$88:$D$92)-MIN(ROW($D$88:$D$92))+1),COLUMNS($F$94:F94)))," ")`

**N.B.**

- *To avoid writing the Formula twice (Since 
  Names are in Col A and Contact numbers in col 
  D), once for Name and for Contact Number, I've 
  Concatenated it, therefore Formula returns 
  Name along with Contact Number in same Cell.*
- Finish the Formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter.**
- Fill Formula Down the Right.

Comment: This looks like it works.  Consider adding a few sentences to explain the gist of **how** it works (T-Shirt case would be enough).